# number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations

Tags: r, mixed-model

I have a data like this, ticks feed on three groups of treated mouses, compare whether the treatment has an effect on ticks' bacteria load.

when I made a mixed model like:

```
lmer.model01 = lmer(log10.load ~ treat + (1|mouse.id/tick.id))
```

The screen says:

```
Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations
```

What happened and how can I change my model?

Comment: Without being able to look at the data, I suspect that you have not enough replicates given your nested grouping structure, i.e. (1|mouse.id) + (1|mouse.id : tick.id). Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713228/lmer-returning-error-grouping-factor-must-be-number-of-observations) or [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57912/random-effects-must-be-less-than-the-number-of-observations-error-in-lmer-pac) for more examples/answers.

Answer (score 8):

@Stefan is probably right.  If you have a single measurement per tick then you should leave the explicit `mouse.id:tick.id` grouping variable out of the model, i.e. use `log10.load ~ treat + (1|mouse.id)`.  Alternatively, if this is a *nested* design (each mouse gets one treatment, each tick is fed on a single mouse, multiple ticks per mice) you could also follow Murtaugh 2007 "Simplicity and complexity in ecological data analysis" *Ecology* 88 and simply compute the average load per mouse, then use a simple `lm(log10.load~treat,data=aggregated_data)`.  (If you insist on fitting the model the way it is you can use `control=lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nlev="ignore")`, but I don't advise it.)