# Repeated measures lmer with groups

Tags: repeated-measures, lme4-nlme

**Background:**
I have data that I'd like to fit a `lmer` model to and a snippet of the data is available below. Basically, predictions were made on the grazing duration `Graz_time` of cattle in 3 groups of 7 cows. Each group was monitored for 3 days before moving on to the next group for another 3 days etc.

```
data <- structure(list(Cow = structure(c(1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 
1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 10L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 21L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 21L, 
10L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 21L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 11L, 13L, 17L, 
19L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 11L, 13L, 17L, 19L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 11L, 13L, 17L, 
19L), .Label = c("5", "15", "31", "55", "68", "74", "78", "84", 
"115", "162", "163", "197", "266", "271", "272", "288", "292", 
"391", "430", "449", "756"), class = "factor"), Group = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "factor"), Day = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "factor"), BCS = structure(c(6L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 
5L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
5L, 4L, 6L, 6L, NA, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 6L, NA, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
6L, 6L, NA, 6L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L), .Label = c("1.5", 
"1.75", "2", "2.25", "2.5", "2.75"), class = "factor"), Parity = 
structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
6L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "factor"), Month_lact = structure(c(1L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 
8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "6", "7", "8", "9"), class = "factor"), L_NL = 
structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("L", 
"NL"), class = "factor"), Grass = c(2396L, 2396L, 2396L, 2396L, 
2396L, 2396L, 2396L, 2756L, 2756L, 2756L, 2756L, 2756L, 2756L, 
2756L, 3451L, 3451L, 3451L, 3451L, 3451L, 3451L, 3451L, 2863L, 
2863L, 2863L, 2863L, 2863L, 2863L, 2863L, 2532L, 2532L, 2532L, 
2532L, 2532L, 2532L, 2532L, 2358L, 2358L, 2358L, 2358L, 2358L, 
2358L, 2358L, 3211L, 3211L, 3211L, 3211L, 3211L, 3211L, 3211L, 
2829L, 2829L, 2829L, 2829L, 2829L, 2829L, 2829L, 2552L, 2552L, 
2552L, 2552L, 2552L, 2552L, 2552L), FieldSize_ha = c(3.14, 3.14, 
3.14, 3.14, 3.14, 3.14, 3.14, 1.64, 1.64, 1.64, 1.64, 1.64, 1.64, 
1.64, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 1.59, 1.59, 1.59, 1.59, 
1.59, 1.59, 1.59, 5.92, 5.92, 5.92, 5.92, 5.92, 5.92, 5.92, 10.41, 
10.41, 10.41, 10.41, 10.41, 10.41, 10.41, 2.85, 2.85, 2.85, 2.85, 
2.85, 2.85, 2.85, 2.85, 2.85, 2.85, 2.85, 2.85, 2.85, 2.85, 2.25, 
2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25, 2.25), Graz_time = c(315L, 444L, 
273L, 426L, NA, 381L, 486L, 369L, 345L, 276L, 348L, 297L, 363L, 
474L, 354L, 375L, 288L, 312L, 447L, 342L, 444L, 291L, 270L, 303L, 
120L, 189L, 426L, 324L, 285L, 531L, 483L, 447L, 366L, 393L, 525L, 
435L, 483L, 447L, 459L, 417L, 651L, 645L, 480L, 462L, 573L, 486L, 
543L, 270L, 288L, 366L, 207L, 327L, 351L, 372L, 399L, 312L, 531L, 
447L, 225L, 528L, 408L, 330L, 363L)), .Names = c("Cow", "Group", 
"Day", "BCS", "Parity", "Month_lact", "L_NL", "Grass", "FieldSize_ha", 
"Graz_time"), row.names = c(NA, -63L), class = "data.frame")
```

Having read [THIS](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259055/repeated-measures-with-lmer-and-logistic-regression) answer I can see that if I construct the following model `mod` that the auto-correlation expected within `Cow` will be accounted for. I also want to account for the variance that may be present as a result of the `Group` category also and so I think that this also accounts for that, i.e. `Cow` is nested within `Group`.

**Question:**
My question is then, do i need to add `Day` as a fixed effect in the model also with it already accounted for in effect in `Cow`? Biologically I am not that interested in `Day` other than that it is a repeated measure design. I have also read [THIS](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186561/number-of-levels-of-each-grouping-factor-must-be-number-of-observations) post which I think suggests in this instance that I may not need `Day` as a fixed effect.

**Further info:**
For some reason I now get an error with this `data` (it is a snippet of what I have) but some advice on the question would be very helpful.

```
mod <- lmer(Graz_time ~ BCS + Parity + Month_lact + L_NL + Grass + FieldSize_ha + (1|Group/Cow), data = data, REML=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your intuition about the inclusion (or exclusion) of `Day` is correct. Given there is a single `Cow` measurements per day as well as `Day` not being of clear biological interest, excluding `Day` is not problematic despite being part of the repeated measurement design.

Having said the above, the problem with this model is that it is over-parametrised for this snippet of data.
For starters, even very lenient rules-of-thumb for multiple regression would have trouble justifying 6 explanatory variables with just 63 observations. Here we have 6 explanatory variables plus a nested random effects design; this seems a bit of stretch.
To that extent, certain levels of the nominal variables used as fixed effects exhibit perfect correlation (the triplet of variables `Month_lact9`, `Parity6` and `BCS1.75`) or in other cases, numerical variables seem quite related (the pair `Grass` and `FieldSize_ha` has a Spearman rank correlation of ~ -0.65). These findings are not catastrophic but also raise some worries about how much additional information we get from each new variable.
As a consequence, somewhat unsurprisingly, any variation due to random effects in terms of `Group`, `Cow` or `Group/Cow` is unfortunately zero when using `REML=TRUE`. Given the above, I think one should examine how to simplify the modelling assumptions and/or obtain more data.

Comment: @user11852 - Thank you very much for your detailed answer - your comments are very valuable. Due to a lack of reputation I cannot of course up vote you! One more question - how can one reduce the impact of correlations between explanatory variables in an analysis such as this?

Comment: The canonical answers to reducing the impact of correlated variables are: 1. Use regularisation. (eg. through Ridge Regression) 2. Use transform variables that are themselves uncorrelated. (eg. through Princ. Component Regression). I would try penalised LMM fitting through `glmmlasso`. Having said that: I think this question will make an interesting new question on its own right.